# in Switch Route Routing time it's working, but now latest new Routes, Route it not working custom route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

in Switch Route  Routing time it's working, but now latest new  Routes, Route it not working custom route
I have wrapped the navbar page and home page in HomeLayoutHOC
can anyone help me :)  how to do this latest version I try but so many things. no result for this

> **I want  'HomeLayoutHOC " route instead of "Route"**

```
->client\src\App.JSX : 
//HOC
import HomeLayoutHOC from "./HOC/Home.Hoc";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
//Component
import Temp from "./Components/temp";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <HomeLayoutHOC path="/" exact element={Temp} />       // <--- I want this to work! 
       // <Route path="/" element={<Temp />} />    //              <-- this working fine 
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> result

[screenshot!](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/84271800/186909314-0e655b88-ef12-490f-a3ea-4ac80c931757.png)

->**client\src\index.jsx :**

```
 import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.CSS";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

-> **client\src\HOC\Home.Hoc.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

// Layout
import HomeLayout from "../Layout/Home.Layout";

const HomeLayoutHOC = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Route
        {...rest}
        component={(props) => (
          <HomeLayout>
            <Component {...props} />
          </HomeLayout>
        )}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default HomeLayoutHOC;
```

->**client\src\Layout\Home.Layout.jsx**

```
import React from "react";

// Components
import Navbar from "../Components/Navbar";

const HomeLayout = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container mx-auto px-4 lg:px-20 ">{props.children}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default HomeLayout;
```

> please give me the possible suggestion for the latest router dom  (Routes, Route)
>
> ## wrapping/composing
>
> How can I spread routeProps to make them available to your rendered Component  the latest router dom  (Routes, Route)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-router-dom@6` removed the need, and compatibility, for custom route components. It's an invariant violation to render anything *other than* a `Route` or `React.Fragment` component in the `Routes` component. Custom route components are replaced with the use of either wrapper components on individual routes wrapping the `element` being rendered, or by layout route components that can wrap any number of *nested* `Route` components.

- Wrapper components render the `children` prop

  ```
  <Route
    path="/"
    element={(
      <Wrapper>
        <Componenet />
      </Wrapper>
    )}
  >
  ```
- Layout Route components render an `Outlet` component for nested routes to render their `element` prop into.

  ```
  <Route element={<Layout />}>
    <Route path="/" element={<Componenet />} />
  </Route>
  ```

You are asking for the Layout Route version since it seems you want to render the `Navbar` component as part of a greater layout.

HomeLayout

```
import React from "react";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "../Components/Navbar";

const HomeLayout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container mx-auto px-4 lg:px-20 ">
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default HomeLayout;
```

App

Render `HomeLayout` on a pathless route ***as*** a [Layout Route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/getting-started/concepts#layout-route). The nested `Route` components render their content into the outlet.

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import HomeLayout from "./path/to/HomeLayout";
import Temp from "./Components/temp";

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<HomeLayout />}>
        <Route path="/" element={<Temp />} />
        ... other routes to render with Home layout and Navbar ...
      </Route>
      ... other routes to render without Home layout and Navbar ...
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

An important aspect you should notice here is that RRDv6 removed [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props), all the old "props" are now only accessible via React hooks in the routed component, i.e. `useNavigate`, `useLocation`, `useParams`, etc. If you are still using React class-based components they won't be able to use React hooks, and since RRDv6 also no longer exports the `withRouter` Higher Order Component, well, you will need to roll your own. See [What happened to withRouter? I need it!](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/getting-started/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it) for details.